# Login before executing a post in unit testing using Chai and Mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test my post function where it only allows data from a user which has specific permission. I have made a login function (tested separately it works). I want to make a test which will perform a login then do a post with data so it does it as an authorised user. As now the test code is working but it does not see a user to be logged in and does it as a normal user.

My current not working code :

```
describe('/POST _json post data as a admin', () => {
        before((done) => {
            let loginInfo = {};
            loginInfo.usr = 'testuser';
            loginInfo.psw = 'mochatesting197';
            chai.request.agent(app)
                .post('/login')
                .send(loginInfo)
                .then((res) => {
                    done();
                });
        });
        it('POST data as a admin', () => {
            let json = {};
            json.module_name = "TEST ENTRY";
            json.module_url = "/TEST_ENTRY";
            json.module_privilege = "testentry;testentry2;testentry3";
            chai.request(app)
                .post('/_json')
                .send(json)
                .then((res) => {
                    res.should.have.status(200);
                    res.body.should.be.a('object');
                    res.body['success'].should.have.property('message');
                }).catch((err) => {
                    throw err;
                });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so after more in-depth research, trial and error methods I found a solution to it.
I still do not understand how it works entirely but it seems like the session has to be returned and acted upon as soon as login has performed.

This is the working version :

```
it('/POST /_json => POST data as a admin', (done) => {
    let json = {};
    json._id = "TEST_ENTRY";
    json.module_name = "TEST_ENTRY";
    json.module_url = "/TEST_ENTRY";
    json.module_privilege = ['testentry', 'testentry2', 'testentry3'];

    let loginInfo = {};
    loginInfo.usr = 'testuser';
    loginInfo.psw = 'mochatesting197';

    let agent = chai.request.agent(app);

    agent.post('/login')
        .send(loginInfo)
        .then((res) => {
            return agent.post('/_json')
                .send(json)
                .then((res) => {
                    res.should.have.status(200);
                    res.body.should.be.a('object');
                    res.body['success'].should.have.property('message').eql('ENTRY HAS BEEN UPDATED');
                    done();
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    throw err;
                });
        });
});
```